# Remove weekly and monthly summaries from collider dropdown

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits, stack-exchange-button

I'm fairly happy with the collider dropdown, and I find myself *not* missing the old responses page. The new reputation page works great, and is a huge improvement. Overall, great job!

The only thing whose point I don't really get is the numeric "reputation/revisions/favourites" overview in the dropdown. 
http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/1059311445.png

Why is this information here? What purpose does it serve?

The weekly and monthly reputation can be checked out on the stats page; I don't think the information is important enough to take up valuable drop-down real estate. Why do I need to know how many revisions I have had this month?

Why not make it just one line:

[image]

Seeing more recent responses there, or a tail view of the stats in the new reputation page, would put the space to much better use.

Comment: @Pekka: Yah, I did misunderstand initially - forgive me. ;) ...and, hm, maybe. I generally make my way to the `activity` page to go through stuff, so these notices are just a little driver over there really.

Comment: @Mr I added a sketch showing what I think it should look like.

Comment: I agree; more recent responses would be far more useful than weekly and monthly totals. There's already a perfectly well-designed interface for that.

Comment: @Pekka, On seeing that, it could be even more concise as an informative menu? http://i.imgur.com/O8F1c.png Granted this isn't on one line, however, is the number of activity links fixed? If so, there can be a fixed width and max-height.

Comment: @MrDisappointment: That makes it more concise horizontally, whereas Pekka's example makes it more concise vertically. As far as I can tell, that's the only difference between the two suggestions. I prefer vertical concision, as it allows even more recent responses to be listed.

Comment: @Cody, I see what you're saying, that's why I wondered if there was a maximum number of displayed responses - isn't there? Also, I'm not trying to push my suggestion either, just giving input. :)

Comment: @Pekka, just a side remark: For me, your post shows that the automatic dummy text "enter image description here" is a bad idea `:-)` (I always delete it by default).

Comment: @Hendrik ah, fair enough! I *never* add an image description, I'll try to pay attention to that in the future.

Comment: @Pekka's - I think you're looking at the interface from only a *daily* user's point of view, many of our users don't visit every day, especially on the smaller sites.