# Wrong vote count on collapsed comments

Tags: bug, status-norepro, google-chrome, comment-voting

Noticed something weird on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-supercollider-redesign).

If the comments are collapsed the vote count of [my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-supercollider-redesign#comment629774_198613) is **zero**.

[image: collapsed]

When expanded the vote count is correctly **three**.

[image: expanded]

Comment: No-repro. Shows as 3 for me when collapsed...

Comment: Yup! repro for me. Not in the first try though.

Comment: @animuson: I've noticed this happening with comments that I've posted only, everybody else's comments appear fine.

Comment: Weird I've up-voted animuson comments but I can't see my vote, and there is no action aviable (since I've already voted). Edit: Fix by posting my comment.

Comment: If I vote on your comment I can reproduce the bug.

Comment: Yup, same results as @Marc-Andre after voting up.

Comment: we just rolled out a pretty significant refactor of the comments system, and there are a handful of minor issues.  I'll be getting to all of them as soon as I reasonably can.

Comment: @BenCollins: I voted on your comment, but there is nothing now. The irony...

Comment: Repro for me too with my comment in OP's screenshot.

Comment: Has anyone been able to reproduce this since 9/27?

Comment: @BenCollins Not for me

Answer (score 8):

Same issue here:

Before:

[image: I guess everybody is having second thoughts on the flogging]

After:

[image: Ah! Flogging is back in the running!]

It seems to only appear on my comments and only when there is a "show more comments" box.

Before the "Show more comments" click, here is the "comment-actions" td:

```
<td class="comment-actions">
</td>
```

After:

```
<td class="comment-actions"><table><tbody><tr>
    <td class="comment-score">
        <span title="number of 'useful comment' votes received" class="warm">7</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        &nbsp;
    </td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
</td>
```

Comment: +1 for freehand red blob thingy :D