# `<style>` in a comment broke the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

See here:

[How to use the 'hover' in html itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120953/how-to-use-the-hover-in-html-itself)

EDIT: I deleted the comment and the page stopped being broken.

Try it yourself.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This happens with anyone who has the ability to edit the comment in question. So, it broke for me too.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Does it only break for the person who posted it? Because once I deleted mine there were a couple new answers posted already.

Comment: It only breaks for anyone who can edit the comment. That means the person who posted it, as well as mods.

Comment: Ah I see. That narrows it down.

Comment: Note that certain HTML tags seem to cause problems as well, but the effects that result from their use vary from simply disappearing on edit, or preventing the rest of the page from being rendered as seen here.

Comment: Yep: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CcKTN.png

Comment: I'll take my Hacker badge whenever you get a sec @BoltClock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this was my screwup. We [just deployed a fairly substantial refactor of the commenting feature(s)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198638/wrong-vote-count-on-collapsed-comments#comment629916_198638).  As with any large refactor, a few things slipped through that shouldn't have, and this was one of them.

This is fixed now.

Comment: That explains all the weird quirks I've seen with commenting in the last week.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn it should explain most of it.