# Would it be possible to have a "hottest unanswered" tab on the MultiCollider drop down?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button, hot-questions

Something that I think would be a valuable tool for the site, and would help get answers to really critical questions, would be to have a "hottest unanswered" tab on the MultiCollider drop down to see all of the really hot questions that haven't been answered yet on the site.

I don't see any reason why this wouldn't be possible. Is this something that could be added?

Comment: Would they stay unanswered for long? This list would change by the *second* (or be hopelessly stale).

Comment: Sometimes questions that are highly upvoted and visited but sit around with no answer stay that way because they require knowledge outside of the domain of the regular users of that stack. Having a "hottest unanswered" tab on the MultiCollider would help draw in outside knowledge.

Comment: @michaelb958 There could be a requirement for the amount of time that it has been "alive" and unanswered before it makes the list.

Comment: The _official_ name is **MultiCollider SuperDropdown™** :-)

Comment: Admittedly I didn't think about that. Here, have a **+1**.

Comment: By the way, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198613/212576

Answer (score 3):

This seems a bit backwards to me.

At least on Physics, our "hottest unanswered" are hard problems that require experts in a rather specific physics subtopic, so showing the question to non-experts from other sites won't help much. I'm pretty sure the same goes (at a lesser degree, maybe) for Sec.SE, EE, Robotics, Astro, SF&F, and probably SO. I can't say as much for other sites as I may not participate on them or I may not have seen any "hot unanswered" questions on them.

So this may end up bringing even *more* clueless people in; which, while not harmful, isn't necessary.

Now, I could get behind showing new, upvoted, unanswered questions in the Multicollider. I discover new sites (which I have a chance of participating on)  this way; I go through the realtime section on SE.com and watch for interesting questions.

Comment: The realtime section is something that don't get enough visibility IMHO.