# Clicking reputation on the new top-bar should take me to the reputation tab of my profile as before

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

With the old top bar, clicking my reputation would take me directly to the reputation tab of my profile for that site.  Now to accomplish the same, I must do two clicks.

For bonus points, clicking the badges should also take me directly to the badges tab (something that didn't happen on the old one).

Comment: Open achievements. You can see there today's total earned reputation by sites. You can also redirect to the specific site's reputation tab from it. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198678/187824. But the problem is that today's total reputation by sites is shown only if we have earned reputation today on more than one site.

Comment: @hims056: a) that's still 2-clicks (or more). b) It requires you have a recent reputation change on the current site to jump to the current site's reputation tab.

Comment: a) with new top bar almost every links require two clicks (except profile page and review page). b) That is an actual problem.

Comment: @hims056: Clicking the Icon-Rep-Badge section of the top bar takes me to my profile with a single click; same as before, except that the entire section now acts as just my name did before. I'll grant you that two clicks isn't the end of the world... but click-avoidance is the essence of my feature request... :)

Comment: I support your request here. I think [a suggestion by @juergen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207518/187824) is better to implement.

Comment: I'd love to get that link back, too.