# Your Community allow me to add the non community site

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

I try to add the community site one which I have not subscribed(registered) yet, but it allow me to add in your community section. I think it should not allow me to do that.

> [image]

Comment: i think this is not a bug, more by-design.

Comment: @Jehof I'm not sure here, that's why I raised it!

Comment: Agree it's unclear and not mentioned anywhere, waiting for official response. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the intended behavior. You have complete freedom to pin any site you want to your list.

We are aware that some people like to browse sites that they don't contribute to.

Comment: But the site switcher reverts to default on such sites, which is a somewhat disorienting experience. I commented on this [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215928/custom-ordering-for-stack-exchange-all-sites-dropdown/222961#comment728073_222961).