# Favicons in top-bar dropdown not SVG

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, stack-exchange-button, favicon

Would it be possible to update the StackExchange button drop-down to include scalable vector graphics (SVG) favicons for each site?

[image]

I didn't notice any mention of this during the [original design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198613/168244) and [beta testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207420/168244) phases.