# Make user-profile site-logos/favicons SVG

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, favicon

Could we update site-logos/favicons to also use scalable vector graphics (SVG) on the profile pages?

[image]

<sub>Original request: [New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253662/168244) (now closed)

Related feature request: [Favicons in top-bar dropdown not SVG](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253635/168244)</sub>