# What does the green plus sign mean?

Tags: support, notifications, top-bar

In the notifications bar there are some notifications with the green plus sign and a number, for example:

> [image]

What do they mean? E.g "+2"

Comment: See the [Help on "Reputation"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) for an explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Feedback request: New top bar and MultiCollider redesign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-multicollider-redesign)

Comment: That is the actual post that explains the 'new' feature in detail.

Comment: @Pat not really. It does not explain what are those numbers. It mentions their existence, but doesn't explain exactly *what* they are. The question here is VERY basic, but still a valid support request.

Comment: This does, right? "All reputation, privileges, and badge updates now appear under a new achievements drop-down, located next to the inbox. (Privileges and badge notifications were 85% of the notification volume). This drop-down will also incorporate reputation updates that are more detailed than we currently display, rolled up by day and post."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the net reputation change due to the event raising the notification.

Positive change would cause the number to be green, negative change would cause a red color.

---

Some common examples for positive rep change: upvotes you get on your posts, answer you posted got accepted, edit you suggested was approved, etc.

Some common examples for negative rep change: downvotes you get on your posts, user was removed, bounty you started, etc.

Comment: Does that mean a question has been voted up?

Comment: Yes @Lschk. For example [this question of yours](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32804/whole-bar-rest-in-6-8-time) has been voted up 9 times - you should see +45 due to this, since every question upvote is worth 5 reputation points to the author.

Comment: Negative changes are simply not shown. No red rep notifications.

Comment: "_negative change would cause a red color._" There is no such thing.

Comment: @CodesInChaos [wrong](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eD4bj.png). See the question now, I've added screenshot to clarify what the OP means.

Comment: @JonasCz wrong. [There is](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eD4bj.png), maybe you just missed getting such notifications. See question now for screenshot that I've added.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Okay, yeah, in the dropdown. I thought you meant in the actual top bar.